Tengo un problema al crear cookies en php a travez de peticiones http en ionic
tengo un backend en php y un frontend en ionic angular, están en dominios distintos y lo que quiero es utilizar jwt para gestionar los inicios de sesión en mi sitio y guardarlos en cookies httponly pero no consigo que cree las cookies. Esta es la forma que realizo la petición http en ionic
login (email: string, password: string): Observable<Response>{
    const formData = new FormData;
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);

    const url = `${ URL }/session/createSession.php`

    return this.http.post<Response>(url, formData);
  }

Estas con los headers que utilizo en php para habilitar el cors
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://misitio.app');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');

Y este es el código que utilizo para crear la cookie
$cookieOptions = [
    "expires" => time() + 3600,
    "path" => "/",
    "domain" => "misitio.app",
    "httponly" => true,
    "secure" => true,
    "samesite" => "None",
];
setcookie("jwt", $jwt, $cookieOptions);

Todo me funciona bien, consigo hacer la petición http, creo correctamente el jwt, pero no me crea la cookie, ¿Como puedo hacer que funcione?
